# How do you get 100% map completion in Oerba?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm trying to get the map and I notice that in all the time periods I have for Oerba, the room near Choco-boca-lina is unmapped, but the door is closed.

Is there a way to map this section? I currently am up to 300AF, and 90% complete. It's also showing the sea as being unmapped, which is odd as I can't get there yet.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in fact 3 different years accessible for Oerba. The sea isn't accessible in both 200AF and 300AF but is accessible in 400AF where its just sand.

To get to the area by Chocolina, it isn't actually talking about inside the room, but the roof I believe. You can access this area with a Chocobo and you have to jump down from the Main Road. This can be done in any year.